# DEP0700 : DEP0700: Registration of the app failed. [0x80073CFB] Un autre utilisateur a déjà installé une version décompressée de l’application

Tags: c#, sql-server, xaml, uwp, visual-studio-2019

I'm doing an UWP app sur Visual studio 2019. I have two accounts on my computer (administrator and user domain) so using tortoise git i recover my projet on my administrator session, because in my administrator session i have my database working fine!

the problem is that i have everything that i switch this exception when compiling:

Error       DEP0700: Registration of the app failed. [0x80073CFB] Un autre utilisateur a déjà installé une version décompressée de l’application. L’utilisateur actif ne peut pas la remplacer par une version en package. Le package entrant en conflit se nomme ab127c45-0836-43b5-8d70-97e15946afed et a été publié par CN=xxxxx.    RecupEnquete

How i can do to avoid this kind of problems??

Maybe my .gitignore file is not good? i use the generic gitignore file

```
## Ignore Visual Studio temporary files, build results, and
## files generated by popular Visual Studio add-ons.

# User-specific files
*.suo
*.user
*.userosscache
*.sln.docstates

# User-specific files (MonoDevelop/Xamarin Studio)
*.userprefs

# Build results
[Dd]ebug/
[Dd]ebugPublic/
[Rr]elease/
[Rr]eleases/
[Gg]enerated Files/
x64/
x86/
build/
bld/
[Bb]in/
[Oo]bj/

# Visual Studo 2015 cache/options directory
.vs/

# MSTest test Results
[Tt]est[Rr]esult*/
[Bb]uild[Ll]og.*

# NUNIT
*.VisualState.xml
TestResult.xml

# Build Results of an ATL Project
[Dd]ebugPS/
[Rr]eleasePS/
dlldata.c

*_i.c
*_p.c
*_i.h
*.ilk
*.meta
*.obj
*.pch
*.pdb
*.pgc
*.pgd
*.rsp
*.sbr
*.tlb
*.tli
*.tlh
*.tmp
*.tmp_proj
*.log
*.vspscc
*.vssscc
.builds
*.pidb
*.svclog
*.scc

# Chutzpah Test files
_Chutzpah*

# Visual C++ cache files
ipch/
*.aps
*.ncb
*.opensdf
*.sdf
*.cachefile
*.VC.db
*.VC.VC.opendb

# Visual Studio profiler
*.psess
*.vsp
*.vspx

# TFS 2012 Local Workspace
$tf/

# Guidance Automation Toolkit
*.gpState

# ReSharper is a .NET coding add-in
_ReSharper*/
*.[Rr]e[Ss]harper
*.DotSettings.user

# JustCode is a .NET coding addin-in
.JustCode

# TeamCity is a build add-in
_TeamCity*

# DotCover is a Code Coverage Tool
*.dotCover

# NCrunch
_NCrunch_*
.*crunch*.local.xml

# MightyMoose
*.mm.*
AutoTest.Net/

# Web workbench (sass)
.sass-cache/

# Installshield output folder
[Ee]xpress/

# DocProject is a documentation generator add-in
DocProject/buildhelp/
DocProject/Help/*.HxT
DocProject/Help/*.HxC
DocProject/Help/*.hhc
DocProject/Help/*.hhk
DocProject/Help/*.hhp
DocProject/Help/Html2
DocProject/Help/html

# Click-Once directory
publish/

# Publish Web Output
*.[Pp]ublish.xml
*.azurePubxml
# TODO: Comment the next line if you want to checkin your web deploy settings 
# but database connection strings (with potential passwords) will be unencrypted
*.pubxml
*.publishproj

# NuGet Packages
*.nupkg
# The packages folder can be ignored because of Package Restore
**/packages/*
# except build/, which is used as an MSBuild target.
!**/packages/build/
# Uncomment if necessary however generally it will be regenerated when needed
#!**/packages/repositories.config

# Windows Azure Build Output
csx/
*.build.csdef

# Microsoft Store app package directory
AppPackages/

# Others
*.[Cc]ache
ClientBin/
[Ss]tyle[Cc]op.*
~$*
*~
*.dbmdl
*.dbproj.schemaview
*.pfx
*.publishsettings
node_modules/
bower_components/

# RIA/Silverlight projects
Generated_Code/

# Backup & report files from converting an old project file
# to a newer Visual Studio version. Backup files are not needed,
# because we have git ;-)
_UpgradeReport_Files/
Backup*/
UpgradeLog*.XML
UpgradeLog*.htm

# SQL Server files
*.mdf
*.ldf

# Business Intelligence projects
*.rdl.data
*.bim.layout
*.bim_*.settings

# Microsoft Fakes
FakesAssemblies/

# Node.js Tools for Visual Studio
.ntvs_analysis.dat

# Visual Studio 6 build log
*.plg

# Visual Studio 6 workspace options file
*.opt

# Files generated by samples with custom Direct2D effects
*.fxlib

# Custom ignores
gallery.xml
project.lock.json
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: This error means "Another user has already installed an uncompressed version of the application." If your machine is multi user, it will still remain in your system before all users uninstalling it. You can change the Package name to a new name in manifest file or let all users uninstall that app. If you try either of the above two methods, will the same issue occur? And Here is a similiar [thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6abaa72a-233b-42cf-bff7-196b35a7ba1d/erreur-dep0700-conflict-with-other-app?forum=toolsforwinapps), you can also check it.

Comment: Thanks! how you can let all the users unistall the app? i already try to change the name it works in my admin account but not on my domain account so...

Comment: Do you mean when you switched to the domain account and changed the name, the error still occurred? Or find the users who have it installed and have them uninstall that app.